# Python - Get item from a list under a list

Tags: python

I have a list like below.

```
list = [[Name,ID,Age,mark,subject],[karan,2344,23,87,Bio],[karan,2344,23,87,Mat],[karan,2344,23,87,Eng]]
```

I need to get only the name 'Karan' as output.

How can I get that?

Comment: how about the completely obvious `list[1][0]`?

Comment: also you should not use `list` as a variable name, it would orverride python's `list` type

Comment: I wouldn't advice on using a list in a list as a preferred data storage format, best use a dictionary in a list, makes each set of data unique and easy to retrieve.

Comment: Also if you're using strings, include them in quotes either `'` or `"`.

Comment: Make sure you provide [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make things easier on everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2D list,

`list[i][j]`

will give you the 'i'th list within your list and the 'j'th item within that list.

So to get Karen you want list[1][0]

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Lio Elbammalf, but decided to provide an answer that made a couple of assumptions that *should have been* clarified in the question:

1. The First item of the list is the headers, they are actually in the list (and not there as part of the question), and they are provided as part of the list because there is no guarantee that the headers will always be in the same order.
2. This is probably a CSV file

Ignoring **2** for the moment, what you would want to do is remove the "headers" from the list (so that the rest of the list is uniform), and then find the index of "Name" (your desired output).

```
myinput = [["Name","ID","Age","mark","subject"],
            ["karan",2344,23,87,"Bio"],
            ["karan",2344,23,87,"Mat"],
            ["karan",2344,23,87,"Eng"]]
## Remove the headers from the list to simplify everything
headers = myinput.pop(0)
## Figure out where to find the person's Name
nameindex = headers.index("Name")
## Return a list of the Name in each row
return [stats[nameindex] for stats in myinput]
```

If the name is guaranteed to be the same in each row, then you can just `return myinput[0][nameindex]` like is suggested in the other answer

Now, if **2** is true, I'm assuming you're using the `csv` module, in which case load the file using the `DictReader` class and then just access each row using the `'Name'` key:

```
def loadfile(myfile):
    with open(myfile) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader)

def getname(rows):
    ## This is the same return as above, and again you can just 
    ## return rows[0]['Name'] if you know you only need the first one
    return [row['Name'] for row in rows]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you can do this

```
_, [x, _, _, _, _], *_ = ls
```

Now `x` will be karan.

Comment: It should be list instead ls. Bravo!

Comment: @SahilAgarwal but don't use `list`.

Comment: @Austin just using OP's variables and being pedantic.